# how to choose correct css class to change element

Tags: css

I would like to change the inner-page-wrap only for the page-id-13133

I can use `.inner-page-wrap {margin-top: 30px}` but how do I specify it is only for this page?

My html is

```
<body class="page page-id-13133 page-template-default logged-in admin-bar bright-design mobile-header-left-logo mhs-tablet-land mh-slideout responsive-fluid sticky-header-enabled sh-dynamic page-shadow header-standard layout-fullwidth   customize-support standard-browser pace-done">
    <div id="main-container" class="clearfix">
        <div class="inner-page-wrap has-no-sidebar clearfix">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the children selector syntax:

```
.page-id-13133 .inner-page-wrap {
   margin-top: 30px
}
```

That selector catches an element that has the class "inner-page-wrap" and is nested (at any level) within an element that has the class "page-id-13133"